# Expand the Taylor series for the following mind-boggling expression at $x = 0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Mind-boggling expression is:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{15}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)(1-x^5)}$$

I started by using the quotient rule and expanding the denominator terms in the hopes of finding some pattern that I can use but to no avail (maybe some other Taylor expansion, or expression that I could simplify into?). Using Wolfram to try see if I can get somewhere using other means, the first $f'(x)$ I got was horrendously complex and it also used the quotient rule. Also, at $x = 0$, it turns out to be $0$ as well. I'm out of ideas. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Hint:Partial Fraction Decomposition

Comment: Perhaps factoring may be of use? $(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: this is not "easy", but you might be able to see that the coefficient of $x^{15+r}$ is the number of ways of writing $r=a+2b+3c+4d+5e$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are nonnegative integers.

Comment: In fact this is the way that I actually managed. Partial fraction decomposition was just taking too much time and its too tedious to do. This is more elegant. Looks like I need to revise some combinatorics again! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would think we can do this alike to working with generating functions.
We have
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k
$$
so your expression is really
$$
f(x) = x^{15} \prod_{j=1}^5 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(x^j\right)^k
$$
and now we need to express the product of the sums as a large individual sum and we are done.

**UPDATE** another thought is to do partial fractions first then the sum would be really easy to come up with...

Comment: Thank you! However is finding one large individual sum really necessary? As it stands, your expression is still pretty much resultant from products of Taylor expansions. Besides, I'm uncertain how such a sum could be found without a monstrous looking expression for it, let alone the coefficients of each term in the summation!

Comment: @jablesauce see update, perhaps partial fractions first may be easier

Comment: Yeah, partial fraction decomposition is quite a blast from the past. What happens in cases when the denominator has irreducible polynomials of a higher degree than $2$? (such as $(1-x^5)$)

Comment: @jablesauce $(1-x^5)$ is not irreducible. The denominator is divisible by $(1-x)^5$ (one term from each factor) and $1-x^5=(1-x)(1+\phi x +x^2)(1-\phi ^{-1}x+x^2)$ where $\phi =\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$ satisfies $\phi ^2=\phi+1$